# Is there a way within a Java Maven project, to call Python code that imports Numpy

Tags: java, python, maven, netbeans, jython

I have successfully put together a demo of Jython using the example:
https://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#one-to-one-jython-object-factories

I am attempting to add "import numpy as np" to the Building.py function, when I do, I get....

Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythoncode/example/Building.py", line 1, in 
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy

Based on some initial research I've started to look at JyNI to solve this problem, but I have not been able to find a good example of:
Java -> Jython -> Python with Numpy -> Jython -> Java

I'm looking for suggestion on how to call a python project that imports numpy from a java project.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/numpy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>numpy</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.2-1.5</version>
</dependency>`
```

[Maven repository] (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/numpy/1.16.2-1.5)

Comment: I can add the dependency to my pom file, but just adding "import numpy as np" to my python file isn't going to work right? Or at least it isn't working for me.